# How to read this superscripted minus sign in a PMF formula

Tags: probability, notation

I was glancing at a probability and statistics review, and I saw some notation that I hadn't seen before. Naturally, I am curious as to how to properly read it and/or use it in the future. My question surrounds the use of the superscripted negative sign as follows:

"Discrete distributions can be specified by the probability mass function (pmf) $p_X(x) = P(X = x)$. The discontinuities in the cdf are at the points where the pmf is positive, and $p(x) = F(x) - F(x^-)$."

Please note, that I am wondering only about the notation - I am confident that I understand the functional and applied aspects of the above quoted passage.

Thanks for helping me learn a little more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it's meant to describe the limit from the left (intuitively, pretend it was $x - \epsilon$ for some really small $\epsilon > 0$):
$$
F(x^-) = \lim_{t \to x^-} F(t)
$$

---

We don't usually see $F(x^+)$, since cdfs are right-continuous, so we could just call that $F(x)$ instead:
$$
F(x^+) = \lim_{t \to x^+} F(t) = F(x)
$$